# how to get an average number from 6 different numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, average

I've got 2 arrays, each array contain 6 different double numbers. both arrays are added to get an average from each element. then the 6 average numbers are produced (each element of array A and array B are added and then divided) now i need to add those 6 average numbers that were calculated, and get a result of those average numbers added and divided by 6.( sorry if im confusing people) i dont know how to start it.
this is my code

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    double examMarks [] = {50,40,60,80,70,11};
    double courseworkmarks [] = {65,49,58,77,35,40};
    System.out.println ("These are the exam marks and the course work    marks");//First row is the exam marks, second row is the course work marks
    computeMarks (examMarks);
    computeMarks1 (courseworkmarks);
    computeResults(examMarks, courseworkmarks);
}

public static void computeMarks(double[] examMarks)
{
    for (int row=0;row<examMarks.length;row++){
        System.out.print (examMarks[row] +"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
public static void computeMarks1(double[] courseworkmarks)
{
    for (int row=0;row<courseworkmarks.length;row++){
        System.out.print (courseworkmarks[row] +"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}


public static void computeResults(double[] examMarks, double[] courseworkmarks)
{

        double avgMarks[] =new double[examMarks.length];
        System.out.println ("The total average of each module is ");
        for(int i=0;i<avgMarks.length;i++){
            int cwWeighting=40;
            avgMarks[i]=(examMarks[i]*(100-cwWeighting)+courseworkmarks[i]*cwWeighting)/100;

            System.out.print(avgMarks[i] + "\t" );
        }
}
```

this is what i've tried so far:

```
 public static computeStageMarks()
        {
            double totalMarks;
            totalMarks = (avgMarks [])/6;
            if (totalMarks<35)
            {
                System.out.println ("Failed" + totalMarks);
            }
            if (totalMarks>=40)
            {
                System.out.println ("Passed" + totalMarks);
            }
            if (totalMarks==35)
            {
                System.out.println ("Passed by compensation" + totalMarks);
            }
```

but it wont work. is the == right for this case? also i need it to recognize the avgMark from the last method. how do i do this?

Comment: do i need to make a new double for totalMarks?

Comment: I think you want `>=` not `==`.  But how is this different from last time you asked this question?

Comment: How you are computing totalMarks?

Comment: yes i want to compute totalmarks, using the the argMarks results

Comment: sorry guys im new to this website and java. sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st question: average of 6 numbers**

You can't work with arrays like that:

```
totalMarks = (avgMarks [])/6;
```

What you got to do is

```
double totalMarks = 0;
```

Then iterate through the array, and one by one add all the scores to `totalMarks`, then divide the result by 6.

**2nd question: how to work with the result of last method:**

This, for example, would work:

```
private static double[] computeAverages() {
  double[] res = new double[6];
  // work with it
  return res;
}

private static void doStuff() {
  double[] averages = computeAverages();
  // now you can use it
}
```

**3rd question: doubles and == operator**

Don't use that. A typical way to work with doubles would run like this:

```
if (value < 35) {
  // ...
} else if (value < 40) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the `avgMarks` in this method, you need to pass that as a parameter.

```
public static computeStageMarks(double[] avgMarks)
```

And alsom to calculate the average, you need to iterate over the array, calculate the sum and then calculate the average.

```
double totalMarks;
double sum = 0.0;
for(double avg : avgMarks ){
    sum += avg;
}
totalMarks = sum/6.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass avgMarks to the function as a parameter

```
public static computeStageMarks(double[] avgMarks)
    {
        double totalMarks;
```

and then calculate totalMarks like this

```
        for(int i=0;i<avgMarks.length;i++)
        {
           totalMarks += avgMarks [i];
        }
        totalMarks = totalMarks/6;
```

and then continue

```
        if (totalMarks<35)
        {
            System.out.println ("Failed" + totalMarks);
        }
        if (totalMarks>=40)
            {
                System.out.println ("Passed" + totalMarks);
            }
        if (totalMarks<40&&totalMarks>=35)
        {
            System.out.println ("Passed by compensation" + totalMarks);
        }
```

Comment: And if totalMarks is equals to 35.5 ? No output.

Comment: Thanks ! made the correction

Comment: thanks, it should work, thats what i tried before, just couldnt remember how to pass avghMarks method as a prameter. thanks alot. ill try it now

Comment: the calculation wont work, i cant get the totalMarks, and because theres nothing to calculate, it wont print anything, coz it has nothing to print. :/

Comment: why can you not get totalMarks, can you post the error ?